# Refresh clock panel plugin after time is changed from terminal

Tags: xubuntu, clock, xfce-panel

I'm changing timezone through terminal, using the following command: `timedatectl set-timezone <timezone>`.

However, the XFCE Clock plugin continues to show previous time, without changing timezone.

How do I force it to update and to show the correct time?

Comment: Logging out of your session seems to refresh the XFCE panel clock.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by understanding what you've done:

```
 set-timezone [TIMEZONE]
           Set the system time zone to the specified value. Available time
           zones can be listed with list-timezones.
```

**If the RTC is configured to be in the local time**

```
this will also update the RTC time. This
               call will alter the /etc/localtime symlink. See localtime(5) for
               more information.
```

*Note that it is not recommended to configure the RTC to local time. UTC is recommended.*

You may wish to use the set-time option instead:

```
set-time [TIME]
           Set the system clock to the specified time. This will also update
           the RTC time accordingly. The time may be specified in the format
           "2012-10-30 18:17:16".
```

Source:

`man timedatectl`

Answer (score 2):

After changing the system time or time zone, one way to update the time shown in the XFCE panel clock plugin by restarting `xfce4-panel`.  This can be done by logging out and back in or by running:

```sh
xfce4-panel --restart
```

Comment: this is simple and doesn't make me read lots. thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click on the clock in the panel
2. Select `Properties`
3. Update the timezone (it seems to use its own timezone)